# REGEX replace string with empty

Tags: regex, hosting, cpanel, whm

I want to make a filter in cPanel that replaces the characters between + and @ which I've got working

Currently I have

```
#(.*?)(?:(?!@).)*
```

My current filter settings in cPanel are:

```
To matches regex: #.+@domain.tld
Forward to: name@domain.tld
```

But I want it to actually deliver to the part before #
Is there any way to tell cPanel to deliver to the part before #?

Comment: Don't use a lookbehind, make the `+` part of the pattern that you match.

Comment: Sorry it needs to "match" that so it sees that the "to" email address contains #service@. It's (.*?)#.+@domain.tld now which seems to work, but I still need it delivered to a address with # and the part between # and @ removed :/
https://regex101.com/r/zF0wB3/9

Comment: Can you show examples of the names you want to match and what they should deliver to? The original question had addresses with `+` in them, what happened to that?

Answer (score 0):

find: (.+)+.+(@.+)
replace with: \1\2

This works for me :)

Comment: I just edited my question. I've got most working except the cPanel part.

My current filter settings in cPanel are:

    To matches regex: #.+@domain.tld
    Forward to: name@domain.tld

But I want it to actually deliver to the part before #
Is there any way to tell cPanel to deliver to the part before #?

Like make a string out of it or something?